# Print pdf file on printer by IP in PHP

Tags: php, pdf, printing, network-printers

I have pdf file on server. And I need pass it to printer by IP and print.
I have Windows and dont have printer , but my boss's site  has Linux and printer (star emae printer).
So he will get me IP address and I need pass pdf file to that printer.

I tried use PDFtoPrinter.exe  and other tools.

I tried this:

```
$printerIP = entity_configuration::getConfigValue('printer_ip');
        echo "Printer IP = ".$printerIP.'<br>';
        $fileToPrint = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/receipts/".CLIENT_ID."/receipt.pdf";
        if(file_exists($fileToPrint)){
            echo "Yes, we have file here:".$fileToPrint.'<br>';
        }
        if (strpos(strtolower(PHP_OS), 'win') !== false) {
            exec("print /D:\"$printerIP\" \"$fileToPrint\"", $output, $returnCode);
        } else {
            exec("lpr -P '$printerIP' -r '$fileToPrint'", $output, $returnCode);
        }
        obj_dump($output);
        if ($returnCode === 0) {
            echo "Print job submitted successfully.";
        } else {
            echo "Failed to submit the print job.";
        }
```

PDFtoPrinter.exe opens printer dialog for enter file name (and then save in Documents , think because i use virtual printer).
Not sure how it will work with real IP. I need have auto name for file.

using **exec("$pathLib $fileToPrint  /s "$printerIP"");** I dont see result, any errors but also dont see any files in Documents folder.
And not sure is **lpr** command correct?

Please help me if you worked with it. Thanks.

Comment: Well 1) a .exe designed for Windows is very unlikely to work on Linux, and 2) on a webserver there is no graphical session when PHP is running, so a dialog box can never appear (that's true whether the server is using Windows or any other OS). So that tool is never going to help you in a website context.

Comment: As for `lpr`, yes that's a Unix/Linux command for sending to a printer. If you're unsure how to use it, there is [more than enough documentation](https://www.google.com/search?q=lpr+linux) already.

Comment: so if my website is on Linux I can use lpr with IP ?

Comment: `I dont see result`...of course you don't, because your PHP code makes no attempt to capture or display the output of the exec command! [Read the `exec` documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) to see the options for getting data returned from it

Comment: I added changes for get result code, and it is 0 , like success

Comment: `if my website is on Linux I can use lpr with IP`...yes, if the tool is installed (which it often is, but you may need to install it first). But I don't think you're setting the options correctly. Read the manual more carefully. https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ulpr.htm has useful guidance (as do many other sites).

Comment: `it is 0 , like success`...why do you think that indicates success? It would help us to understand better if you show us what code you changed - you can [edit] your question. If you want to capture _all_ the output, you have to set the `output` argument, as per the documentation.

Comment: ok, I added changes
Output is empty
Unfortunately cant check know on real printer

Comment: `Output is empty`...how do you know? Your PHP code doesn't attempt to display the contents of `$output` after you run `exec`!! It will not appear on your screen just by magic. At least try `var_dump($output);`. Look at Example #1 in the exec() documentation, for how to use it.

Comment: I added obj_dump($output); and it is empty

Comment: What is obj_dump? That isn't a regular PHP command. Why can't you just use the commands like var_dump or print_r as mentioned by me, and by the documentation? If you get an instruction designed to help you, please follow it instead of inventing your own method, and you may make more progress (or at least, you won't cause extra doubt and confusion for the people attempting to assist you!).

Comment: Here's another thing...have you logged onto the linux server and tested the lpr command directly from a terminal window? Make sure you can get it working and print something that way, before trying to integrate it with PHP. Then you can go one step at a time and debug it more easily, without having to worry about whether the PHP integration is interfering with the process.